# How to add "image()" formula in CSV export?

Tags: magento2, csv, export

How to add **"=image()"** formula in `$stream->writeCsv()` CSV export?

Please help me I want to keep formula while export csv file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I got the answer. We can not able to add formula in CSV file because
>   of Magento2 add `' '(Empty space)` where add `('=', '+', '-')`.

Check the bellow file path and code you will get it.

```
vendor/magento/framework/Filesystem/Driver/File.php:757

if (isset($value[0]) && in_array($value[0], ['=', '+', '-'])) {
    $data[$key] = ' ' . $value;
}
```

> Because of Security enhancement for CSV data processing by Excel-like
>   applications.

Thanks,